# What is the difference between Mustache.js, Handlebars.js and Underscore.js?

Tags: backbone.js, template-engine

I would like to choose a **template engine** for the `Backbone.js` framework I'll use inside my MVC application.

I've read Backbone.js is compatible with `Mustache.js`, `Handlebars.js` and `Underscore.js` by default, does exist some important difference between these template engines or they do almost the same thing?

Also, does exists **other template engines** compatible with `Backbone.js` should be seriously considered?

Comment: See here: [The client-side templating throwdown: mustache, handlebars, dust.js, and more](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more).  Underscore is the only one of the three that you mentioned that allows Javascript embedding.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/10194921

Comment: and http://garann.github.com/template-chooser/

Comment: ahah! you are a boss! the last link is nice!

Answer (score 7):

Mustache and Handlebars are what are known as "logic-less template engines." They force developers not to include any overly complex logic in the view, only the most basic control structures needed to output data, keeping the HTML (or other content) clean. This also means they are completely language agnostic; you should be able to use them with any programming/scripting language with little trouble.

Underscore however is different. It's a JavaScript library in itself, like Prototype or jQuery, and comes with it's own templating engine. The templates have access to any method or helpers within the library, meaning the templates are strictly tied to JavaScript and house a lot more of the logic.

Comment: Mustache is logicless, Handlebars is not.